# API vk и загрузка фотографий

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Что мне нужно для того, чтобы залить фото в свой паблик ВК, и при этом использовать это фото в посте? **Для последнего знаю, что можно использовать метод постинга на стену, но как прилепить изображение?**

P.S - видел в сети куча библиотек, но я стараюсь их избегать - поэтому вариант не очень.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы выложить на стену фотографию, необходимо выполнить следующую последовательность:

1. При помощи метода [`wall.getPhotoUploadServer`](https://vk.com/pages?oid=-17680044&p=wall.getPhotoUploadServer) получить адрес, на которую можно будет загрузить изображение;
2. `POST`'ом отправить изображение на полученную ссылку, в ответ прийдет `hash` сохраненного изображения;
3. Через метод [`wall.savePost`](https://vk.com/pages?oid=-17680044&p=wall.savePost) передать полученный ранее `hash` изображения.

Более подробно в [спеке VK](https://vk.com/pages?oid=-17680044&p=Uploading_Files_to_the_VK_Server_Procedure).